# Библиотека для работы с форматом Excel

Tags: excel, парсер, c++

Есть прайс-лист товаров по категориям в формате Excel. Надо сравнить его содержание с БД и добавить/удалить/изменить записи в базе. 
Подскажите хорошую библиотеку для работы с Excel из С++. Желательно кроссплатформенную.

P.S. LibXL не предлагать, т.к. платная.

Comment: Интересно, а библиотеки OpenOffice можно как-нибудь использовать?

Comment: Там вроде же java. Сейчас покопаю в эту сторону.

Comment: Ни, на сайте LibreOffice написано на чистом английском, что сама программа написана на С++, а джаву можно использовать для написания plugin'ов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьми без библиотеки, сохрани Экселевский документ в текстовом формате с разделителем табуляции и отпарсь разделяя табуляцией. Так проще и без библиотек.

Я такой штукой пользуюсь для парсинга в WEB

2 [[@Fe1iX](/users/4410/fe1ix)](/users/4410/fe1ix)

> "если там текст, кавычками.. и между
> некоторыми ячейками у меня получается
> по 8 табуляци"

Текст и кавычки это вообще пофиг. Ты при сохранении документа получаешь нормальный текстовый файл где каждый столбец разбит от предыдущего символом табуляции.

Я просто не понимаю ты как их парсишь?

в php же все просто

```
//читаешь строку
$mas=explode("\t",str);//потом её 
ну а дальше 
$mas[0]-первый столбец
$mas[n]-последний столбец
```

И всё. причем тут сколько там внутри кавычек или еще чего, а то что там записи с "как ты говоришь" 8 табуляций, значит поля эти просто пустые.

Comment: Пробовал, но проблема в том, что Excel криво эскпортирует в CSV-формат. Т.е. он не выделяет содержимое ячейки, если там текст, кавычками.. и между некоторыми ячейками у меня получается по 8 табуляций. А если учесть, что строки в ячейках могут содержать те же кавычки, кучу пробелов и иногда табуляции, то данный вариант не очень подоходит.

Comment: Ну нужно в CVS простой текстовый файл. я же написал что именно в текстовом не CVS

Comment: И к простому текстовому относится все, что я написал выше :) В итоге пришлось изобретать свой парсер.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы применила com - технологии.  Забрала бы в программу содержимое с листа Excel да подключай базу и сравнивай

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно кроссплатформенное решение, т.к. планируется работа под Mac OS X. Да и нету у меня в ближайшем доступе Windows и Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

В одном из своих проектов работал с [**ExcelFormat,**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelFormat.aspx) нареканий не было, но, возможно, что спектр решаемых задач узковат.

Comment: Попробую. А как он работает с большими файлами? 100к строк и больше.

Comment: @Fe1iX В моем случае работал с таблицами 1-10к строк, изменений в отзывчивости приложения не заметил.