# Есть ли php фреймворк для работы с excel таблицами?

Tags: php, excel, framework

Мне нужен фреймворк (желательно php) который может работать с excel таблицами.

Нашел такие темы:
[Библиотека для работы с форматом Excel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-excel) и [C# работа с Excel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612208/c-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-excel). Но это не то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая библиотека `phpexcel`, входящая в состав `phpoffice`. На фреймворк она может и не тянет, но она сделана с использованием ООП, поддерживает кучу функций и имеет хорошую документацию. Работает с xls, xlsx, а в нагрузку ещё с кучей форматов типа CSV.
P.S. Кстати ставится через Composer, если это нужно в Вашем проекте. Но и руками без всяких пакетных менеджеров прикручивается без проблем.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш ответ. Пойду посмотрю что это за библиотека и как с ней работать.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуюсь [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) библиотека не фреймворк.

Пример вывод столбцов с вкладки контакты производителей

```
  <?

include 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$File = "shema.xls";
 
$Excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($File);
//$Excel = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet1'); 
$Excel->setActiveSheetIndex(9);
//$Excel->setActiveSheetByName("Контакты производителей");
$ListArray = $Excel->getSheetNames("Контакты производителей");

 echo "<pre>";
//  print_r($ListArray);
 echo "</pre>";



$nList=0;
foreach($ListArray as $it)
{
    if($it == "Контакты производителей")
    {
        $Excel->setActiveSheetIndex($nList); //Працюватимимо з контактами
        break;
    }
$nList++;
//echo $it;
}

 
# С какой строки начинаются данные
$Start = 1;
?>
 <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
 <?

for ($i= $Start; $i <= $Excel->setActiveSheetIndex($nList)->getHighestRow(); $i++)
{
    $Row = new stdClass();
    $Row->id = $i;
        
    $Ai = $Excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i )->getValue(); 
    $Bi = $Excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i )->getValue();   
    $Ci = $Excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$i )->getValue(); 
    if($Ai == null) continue;
        
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$i}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Ai}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Bi}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Ci}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    
    
   // $Res[] = $Row;
}

?>

 </table>
<?


//=============================



$nList=0;
foreach($ListArray as $it)
{
    if($it == "Контакты магазинов")
    {
        $Excel->setActiveSheetIndex($nList); //Працюватимимо з контактами
        break;
    }
$nList++;
//echo $it;
}

 
# С какой строки начинаются данные
$Start = 1;
?>
 <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
 <?

for ($i= $Start; $i <= $Excel->setActiveSheetIndex($nList)->getHighestRow(); $i++)
{
    $Row = new stdClass();
    $Row->id = $i;
        
    $Ci = $Excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i )->getValue();   //Місто
    $Gi = $Excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J'.$i )->getValue();   //Телефон
    $Ei = $Excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F'.$i )->getValue();   //Кратко
    $Fi = $Excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$i )->getValue();   //ТЦ
    $Ki = $Excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$i )->getValue();   //Адреса
    if($Ai == null) continue;
    if($Ci == "") break;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$i}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Ci}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Gi}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Ei}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Fi}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Ki}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    
    
   // $Res[] = $Row;
}

?>

 </table>
<?

/*
     
 echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Res);
 echo "</pre>"*/
    ?>
```

Пример не прочищен просто скопировал вставил свой