# Пересохранить файл csv в xlsl

Tags: c, shell, powershell

Есть программа на СИ она работает с csv для удобства нужно на выходе выдавать xlsx работает под windows 10 но скорее всего сгодится и какое то решение под unix/linux. Я думаю что можно пробовать как-то запустить процесс с excel и там вызвать какой то метод или функцию для сохранения в формате, подскажите в каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: Для С++ этот вопрос обсуждался тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-excel

Comment: Мне такая библиотека не нужна, весь код расчитан на работу с текствым файлом, нужно потом просто в формат excel его привести